# session object is null after update

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm populating an object model with a linq query. The model looks like this:

```
MyModel{
DateTime AppointDate {get; set;}
int TotalAppoints {get; set;}
int AppointDuration {get; set;}
}
```

The linq-to-sql query looks like that:

```
    public static GetAppointsFromDB(params){

    var MyQuery = from....where...
                  select new MyModel{
                    AppointDate = ...,
                    TotalAppoints = ...,
                    AppointDuration =...};

    return MyQuery as MyModel;}
```

In the master page, I'm looking to load the result of this query in the session like this:

```
if (Session["Appoints"] == null) {Session["Appoints"] = GetAppointsFromDB(...);}
```

When I run with the code, the session is always null. I added this line a second time, just right after, and the query runs again. When I'm looking to use the session at some other point in the code, it is null too there too. The query works because when I put a breakpoint on the return statement, I see the object properly filled.

Please let me know where the problem comes from, I'm stuck on this seemingly simple problem and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static GetAppointsFromDB(params)
{

  var MyQuery = from....where...
                select new MyModel{
                AppointDate = ...,
                TotalAppoints = ...,
                AppointDuration =...};

  return MyQuery as MyModel;
}
```

Let's assume this method actually returns `MyModel`, so:

```
public static MyModel GetAppointsFromDB(params)
```

Now what you are seeing is probably that `MyQuery` results in something that cannot be cast to `MyModel`, that's why it returns null - why do you need the `As` operator in the first place? If your query always returns a single instance of type `MyModel` you should just

```
return MyQuery;
```

If your query contains an *enumeration* of MyModel (and this is what it looks like) and you only want to return one you could use

```
return myQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

instead.

Comment: ah ha! It works. What's the difference between using FirstOrDefault and SingleOrDefault?

Comment: `SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception if your query returns more than one item - `FirstOrDefault()` will just take the first (default behavior is the same if your query returns no items)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's the MasterPage.Load event is firing after the Page.Load event.
Try to use the Init event of the Master Page, which will run before the Load events.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyQuery` variable is of type `IQueryable<MyQuery>`, not `MyModel` as you trying to cast. So this line `return MyQuery as MyModel` return `null`.

Try to change it to e.g.

```
var MyQuery = from....where...
              select new MyModel{
                  AppointDate = ...,
                  TotalAppoints = ...,
                  AppointDuration =...};

return MyQuery.ToList();
```

and it should work.